# Can't find fish disease, Fish body Poped Up

Tags: fish, aquarium, medicines, diseases

It's sometime since my fish body poped up with color of white, and then it's tail some how more blody, i asked someone and send picture he didn't reply, so i went to store yesterday, and he replied to use ceftriaxone, but since i used that once before for another disease maybe a month ago, once the main shop owner came buy, i again asked the same question, so he replied it's some kind of Fungus, and i have to use tetra cycling pill 1 per 30 littre, so my aquarium is 108 littre, and i add it, but once i did some research, ... i didn't found that sign, but seeing fungus on internet, at firsts is wasn't like that at all, that was somehow different, so i wanted to make sure... also since it took a week, my fish body got scare in that place,...

Here are some photos...

[image: Body And Tail]
[image: Side View, See How Much It Poped Up]
BTW, these image are from today, so its more than just to get poped out, it also like a wound

if by any chance, the medicine was wrong, or i have to add any other things, please tell me,...

Let me note something else before hit the "Post your question" button.
around two week ago, i was about to remove a cutted out leaf, and once i saw something start to move like a single root in the aquarium, since the movement were so much and rounded shape, i though it was a worm... very slim like a single root, white, and with so much and rounded movement... sincei t were close to outlet of filter, i'm not sure, bTW, i tried to remove it, took it with the leaf, not sure if it removed... any thing about that?

---

### Update 2016-09-05

Today, he losses most of his last tail fin, he got slower, so at last i could take him. during this time they (the big shop owner) recomended 'tetracycling' and i give them, twise, 2 day ago i bougth cefteriaxone for another couse, and just to make sure, so since then his stomach seem less poped, but still... i don't know what to say,

I didn't have any more cefteriaxone, so after seperating him, i add one glass of aquarium water, which contain a little of that drug, add a little tetracycling, and i also add salt, he survived till now, if he get better, i shall add some salt to the aquarium it self, i saw some very small sign of sickness on some fishes during these recent days.

Here are some new picture of that fish:

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### Update 2016-09-06

The fish just died  I still kept the body of i found time today,  I'll take it to someone maybe other don't meet the same destiny...